# Choosing the optimal and realistic solution from NFC UHF RFID

Tags: image-processing, nfc

I don't post much often so m unaware about the conventions of asking a question,
I currently am working on my final year project a part of which includes electronic attendance, i have gone through a few options which include image processing, NFC, UHF.
As far as the NFC based technology is concerned the attendance shall be marked via cell phones and NFC tag, the problem however is that this NFC based technology wont be a feasible solution as we are talking about marking attendances from as far as 50 feet(anywhere within a room of 50 feet).
Under these situation i am looking for recommendations regarding which technology to look into.
Thank you all for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stated requirements, it looks like a setup with purely passive UHF RFID Tags will not do what you want. The current real world distances for UHF Tags held or worn by people is 5m max (much less than your 50' requirement)

If you really need to read out to 50', I suggest the following alternatives:

1) BAP (Battery Assisted Passive). These are readable out to ~100' but have a battery and inherent shelf / use life

2) Active. BLE or Low Power WiFi or another system where the tag actively transmits (as opposed to back scattering). These systems will provide you with enough link budget to meet your distance requirements.